# BottomAppBar height gets bigger when using window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)

Tags: height, statusbar, transparent, bottombar

I am trying to achieve transparent status bar by using window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false) and statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT. I achieved my goal, but when I introduced BottomAppBar, its size (padding to be exact) is doubled. What might be the issue?

With window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false):

[image]

Without window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false):

[image]

Main Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityMain">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:elevation="1dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="auto"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_bar_menu" />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Got to the answer quickly than I thought I would. I forgot to calculate the insets, so adding this piece of code made everything working again:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView) { view, windowInsets ->
    val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    view.updatePadding(bottom = insets.bottom)
    WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
}
```