# 3 buttons navigation hardly visible in edge-to-edge setup, even after setting android:enforceNavigationBarContrast=true

Tags: android

I have a edge-to-edge implementation as follow.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private void edgeToEdgeIfPossible() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            return;
        }

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76164938/why-the-height-of-bottom-app-bar-grow-significantly-when-displaying-content-edge
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076365/bottomappbar-height-gets-bigger-when-using-window-setdecorfitssystemwindowsfals
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(getWindow().getDecorView(), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets statusBarsInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars());
            Insets navigationBarsInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars());

            View parentLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

            parentLinearLayout.setPadding(
                    parentLinearLayout.getPaddingLeft(),
                    statusBarsInsets.top,
                    parentLinearLayout.getPaddingRight(),
                    navigationBarsInsets.bottom
            );

            return WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED;
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edgeToEdgeIfPossible();
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.Edgetoedge" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">true</item>

        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">
            @android:color/transparent
        </item>

        <!-- Optional: set to transparent if your app is drawing behind the status bar. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">
            @android:color/transparent
        </item>

        <!-- Optional: set the status bar light and content dark. -->
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">
            true
        </item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Edgetoedge" parent="Base.Theme.Edgetoedge" />
</resources>
```

---

I tested it against 3 buttons navigation bar. I expect

```
<item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">true</item>
```

will able to make the 3 buttons navigation bar visible, as described in https://medium.com/@thereallukesimpson/tips-to-display-edge-to-edge-screen-content-in-an-existing-android-app-in-compose-xml-d11852134240

[image]

However, it is same color as my app background, and hardly visible.

May I know, how can I make the 3 buttons navigation visible, in edge-to-edge setup?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [`enableEdgeToEdge()` method](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge#enable-edge-to-edge-display)? What does it look like if you use that?

Comment: I can never make `EdgeToEdge.enable(this);` work based on my experience. For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78011528/72437 If I use `EdgeToEdge.enable(this);`, I will get https://i.imgur.com/cYHWOmG.png (Guess I still need to handle `Insets` manually because it is blocking the `TextView`). Do you have any idea why `android:enforceNavigationBarContrast` doesn't work for the above case? Thanks.